# How to create dataset in the same format as the FSNS dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

I'm working on this [project](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr) based on TensorFlow.

I just want to train an OCR model by attention_ocr based on my own datasets, but I don't know how to store my images and ground truth in the same format as FSNS datasets.

Is there anybody also work on this project or know how to solve this problem?

Comment: were you able to get this working for you? Can you share the script you used to prepare your own data?

Comment: Sorry, I have not reproduce the process of preparing datasets based on my own images. I got stuck in this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093932/invalidargumenterror-when-traing-attention-ocr-assign-requires-shapes-of-both

Comment: Your project link is dead.

Comment: @JianboWang can you please share the dummy datasets of FSNS which u created.

Comment: @JianboWang Do you have a tutorial to create the FSNS dataset?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The data format for storing training/test is defined in the FSNS paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.03970.pdf (Table 4).

To store tfrecord files with tf.Example protos you can use [tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter](http://tf.python_io.tfrecordwriter/). There is [a nice tutorial](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/), an existing [answer on the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849617/how-do-i-convert-a-directory-of-jpeg-images-to-tfrecords-file-in-tensorflow) and a [short gist](https://gist.github.com/gvanhorn38/ac19b85a4f7b5fb9e82e04f4ac6d5566).

Assume you have an numpy ndarray `img` which has `num_of_views` images stored side-by-side (see Fig. 3 in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.03970.pdf)):
[image]
and a corresponding text in a variable `text`. You will need to define some function to convert a unicode string into a list of character ids padded to a fixed length and unpadded as well. For example:

```py
char_ids_padded, char_ids_unpadded = encode_utf8_string(
   text='abc', 
   charset={'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2},
   length=5,
   null_char_id=3)
```

the result should be:

```py
char_ids_padded = [0,1,2,3,3]
char_ids_unpadded = [0,1,2]
```

If you use functions `_int64_feature` and `_bytes_feature` defined in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/gvanhorn38/ac19b85a4f7b5fb9e82e04f4ac6d5566) you can create a FSNS compatible tf.Example proto using a following snippet:

```py
char_ids_padded, char_ids_unpadded = encode_utf8_string(
   text, charset, length, null_char_id)
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(
  feature={
    'image/format': _bytes_feature("PNG"),
    'image/encoded': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()),
    'image/class': _int64_feature(char_ids_padded),
    'image/unpadded_class': _int64_feature(char_ids_unpadded),
    'height': _int64_feature(img.shape[0]),
    'width': _int64_feature(img.shape[1]),
    'orig_width': _int64_feature(img.shape[1]/num_of_views),
    'image/text': _bytes_feature(text)
  }
))
```

Comment: Hi, Gorban, thx a lot for your response. There are another two questions:
1.Does it works on Chinese datasets?
2.If in one image, there are several groundtruths(more text segments), does it also works?

Comment: 1. It works with any language
2. It doesn't work for multiple unrelated text regions

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the below code directly:

```
"'image/encoded': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()),"
```

In my code, I wrote this:

```
_,jpegVector = cv2.imencode('.jpeg',img)
imgStr = jpegVector.tostring()
'image/encoded': _bytes_feature(imgStr)
```