# InvalidArgumentError when traing Attention_ocr : Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match

Tags: python

I am working on Alex Gordan's [Attention_ocr](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr) project.
I have follow the guide and store my data in FSNS format acoording to Alex's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430310/how-to-create-dataset-in-the-same-format-as-the-fsns-dataset).

However, when I run command:
python train.py --dataset_name=rctw

Error occurs and error message shows as follow:

```
Caused by op u'save/Assign_175', defined at:
  File "train.py", line 209, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "train.py", line 205, in main
    train(total_loss, init_fn, hparams)
  File "train.py", line 153, in train
    init_fn=init_fn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 688, in train
    saver = saver or tf_saver.Saver()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1040, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1070, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 675, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 414, in _AddRestoreOps
    assign_ops.append(saveable.restore(tensors, shapes))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 155, in restore
    self.op.get_shape().is_fully_defined())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 47, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [3794,3506] rhs shape= [422,134]
     [[Node: save/Assign_175 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@AttentionOcr_v1/sequence_logit_fn/SQLR/LSTM/attention_decoder/weights"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](AttentionOcr_v1/sequence_logit_fn/SQLR/LSTM/attention_decoder/weights/Momentum, save/RestoreV2_175/_15)]]
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_141/_168 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_715_save/RestoreV2_141", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](save/RestoreV2_141)]]
```

Since I have use python/datasets/fsns.py as the example to create my rctw.py, and include it in datasets/init.py as fsns, why this error occurs? Maybe there is some hardcode in your project so they always call "134 charset"

Hope for author or anyother's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code use a pretrained model stored in my tmp path, I clean up /tmp to solve it.