# Chars, padding and nulls for custom dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I am working on a custom dataset to train and test the models attention_ocr and street, but am unclear on what the function encode_utf8_string [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430310/how-to-create-dataset-in-the-same-format-as-the-fsns-dataset/44461910#44461910) is doing. What is the purpose of the padding and use of nulls in determining the char arrays (padded and unpadded)?

Given the following charset, length (5), and null char (3):

```
{'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2},
```

Are these the correct padded and unpadded results (note spaces in text)?

```
'bc': padded: [1,2,3,3,3], unpadded: [1,2]
'a a': padded: [0,3,0,3,3], unpadded: [0,3,0]
```

Comment: Do you want to convert your dataset to FSNS dataset format?.  In this paper `null` is `133` and `space` is `0`. Check: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/attention_ocr/python/datasets/testdata/fsns/charset_size%3D134.txt

Comment: Yes, I have images (each in folders by text/label) and a file with all the expected text from the images. I am looking to combine those exactly as the FSNS dataset was created. I see the space now (0), but not sure the use of null, or how padding should be done. Why is there a padded and unpadded label (class)?