# How to create dataset in the same format as the FSNS dataset for attention_ocr？

Tags: python, tensorflow, attention-model

I tried code for answer in [How to create dataset in the same format as the FSNS dataset？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430310/how-to-create-dataset-in-the-same-format-as-the-fsns-dataset/44461910#44461910)

for image class I am getting the following error:

```
File "createFsns.py", line 101, in 'image/class': _int64_feature(char_ids_padded), File "createFsns.py", 
line 52, in _int64_feature return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
TypeError: [20, 10, 0, 2, 10, 15, 0, 1, 1, 3] has type list, but expected one of: int, long
```

I corrected `tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value])` to `tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value)` Now getting this error:

```
tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value)) TypeError: Value must be iterable
```

Comment: corrected tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]) to tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value)

Now getting this error:-
tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))
TypeError: Value must be iterable

Comment: rohit saluja, your solution worked for me. Why not make it an answer?