# Transform an image of handwritten notes to text

Tags: java, python, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, handwriting-recognition

I have hundreds of images of handwritten notes. They were written from different people but they are in sequence so you know that for example `person1` wrote `img1.jpg` -> `img100.jpg`. The style of handwriting varies a lot from person to person but there are parts of the notes which are always fixed, I imagine that could help an algorithm (it helps me!).

I tried `tesseract` and it failed pretty bad at recognizing the text. I'm thinking since each person has like 100 images is there an algorithm I can train by feeding it a small number of examples, like 5 or less and it can learn from that? Or would it not be enough  data? From searching around it seems looks like I need to implement a `CNN` (e.g. [this paper](https://www.ijeat.org/wp-content/uploads/papers/v8i2s2/B10370182S219.pdf)).

My knowledge of `ai` is limited though, is this something that I could  still do using a library and some studying? If so, what should I do going forward?

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/ Try looking into tesseract OCR

Comment: What you can do, is to take each image and extract each word from it (using a pre-trained CNN) - then combine each word to a sentance. Otherwise, you can look at RNN/LSTM, but I would go with CNN first

Answer (score 2):

There are many OCRs out there and some perform better than others. However, this is a field that has improved a lot recently with the Deep Neural Networks. I would consider using a Cloud provider such as Azure, Google Cloud or Amazon. Your upload the image and they return the metadata.

For instance:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/

If you don't want to use cloud services for any reason, I would consider using TensorFlow... but some knowledge is required:

[Tensorflow model for OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610527/tensorflow-model-for-ocr)

Comment: I will try `Tensorflow` then as `tesseract` doesn't seem capable of handling this handwritten notes.

Answer (score 1):

This is called `OCR` and there has been a progress. Actually, here is an example of how simple it is to parse an image file to text using `tesseract`:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract


def ocr_core(file):
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(file)
    return text


print(ocr_core('sample.png'))
```

## BUT

I am not very sure that it can recognize different types of handwriting. You can give it a try yourself to find out. If you want to try the `python` example you need to import `tesseract` but first things first to install `tesseract` on your OS and add it to your `PATH`.

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't return any text. As a sanity check I tried [something easier](https://imgur.com/a/QyIqrhh) and it [actually gave me something back](https://imgur.com/a/2jki7ao).