# Tesseract can't recognize images with handwritten text, what can I do?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, handwriting-recognition

As I asked in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395079/) the problem I'm facing is that I have hundreds of images of handwritten notes. They were written from different people but they are in sequence so you know that for example `person1` wrote `img1.jpg` -> `img100.jpg`. The style of handwriting varies a lot from person to person but there are parts of the notes which are always fixed (maybe that can help an algorithm).

I followed one user suggestion to use `tesseract` but it couldn't recognize any of the text. The text is not in engligh but I did use the appropriate language data file.

My knowledge of `ai` is limited but from searching and looking at some papers it looks like this could be done with a `CNN`. Can someone guide as to what I should do from here? I'd like to go forward with the project but I also don't have a lot of time to learn about neural networks. How challenging is it to implement one that solves this task?

Comment: Please attach some sample images to your question, and I will be able to answer if ABBYY SDK can do that.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use tesseract for handwriting recognition. You can train tesseract for handwriting recognition but out of the box it works well for printet text and a lot of fonts and languages.

Here are two links how to train it yourself:

- [Tesseract handwriting with dictionary training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310287/tesseract-handwriting-with-dictionary-training)
- [Using Tesseract for handwriting recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556443/using-tesseract-for-handwriting-recognition)

I had best results with Azure Recognition and good with Amazon Recognition: https://aws.amazon.com/en/recognition
I would like to have a offline java library for it but didn't found any yet.
My next step will be to try  ABBYY services because they can also focus on seperated handwritten characters: https://abbyy.technology/en:features:ocr:icr

**Update**

If somebody find a library or good service even years later I would be happy to see them in the comments.

Comment: Hey @timguy were you able to find any offline mechanism for this yet?

Comment: No didn't found anything.
You could try tesseract again and read this article about preprocessing: https://joseurena.medium.com/tesseract-ocr-evaluating-handwritten-text-recognition-1c6db85b2e7f
Also checkout this library but I also did not tried: https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR 
Let me know if you found something.